# EnterAnimation not working on MvxFragment

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am using MVVMCross5 for Android. I have no issue with the Fragment navigation, but fragment animations are not working. I am using EnterAnimation property on MvxFragmentPresentation attribute on the fragment definition. am I missing anything? Below is the my fragment definition:

```
[MvxFragmentPresentation(ActivityHostViewModelType = typeof(MainViewModel), FragmentContentId = Resource.Id.frame_layout, AddToBackStack = true, EnterAnimation = Android.Resource.Animation.SlideInLeft)]
public class LabelRequestDetailFragment : BaseFragment<LabelRequestDetailViewModel>
{
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        return this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.label_request_detail, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set both EnterAnimation and ExitAnimation for it to work.

[This](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/a78401df531d18b2f4bbf2120dd8a068d3c3b6c2/MvvmCross/Droid/Droid/Views/MvxAndroidViewPresenter.cs#L467) line in the source code makes the check.

Reason for this limitation is the Android SDK requires both as parameter.

Comment: Thanks. It works after setting the both EnterAnimation and ExitAnimation resources, but now, it is only showing enter animation but not exit animation.